# event listener in FOR works only for the last one

Tags: javascript

My event listener works only for the last element, even if I hover the first or second one. It actually works as I wanted, but I need it to be functional for all of them...

It show 3 divs with bacgkorund images (that's fine), but when I hover each of them, the last one hover always. I'm not skillful in JS and FOR things, so I don't see the problem there.

My HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="produkt">
        <div class="obrazek" img-before="img/prod.png" img-after="img/prod_h.jpg"></div>
        <div class="nazev">MATCHA KULINARY</div>
        Cena 260Kč<br> 
        <span>zobrazit</span>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="produkt">
        <div class="obrazek" img-before="img/prod_kat.png" img-after="img/prod_h.jpg"></div>
        <div class="nazev">MATCHA KULINARY</div>
        Cena 260Kč<br> 
        <span>zobrazit</span>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="produkt">
        <div class="obrazek" img-before="img/prod.png" img-after="img/prod_h.jpg"></div>
        <div class="nazev">MATCHA KULINARY</div>
        Cena 260Kč<br> 
        <span>zobrazit</span>
      </a>
```

My CSS:

```
.prod .produkt .obrazek{
  width: 70%;
  height: 250px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

My JS:

```
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.obrazek');
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      var element = elements[i];
      if(element) {
        var before = element.getAttribute('img-before');
        var after = element.getAttribute('img-after');

        if(before && after) {
            element.style.background = 'url(' + before + ')'; // set the first background

            element.addEventListener('mouseover', function(event) {
                element.style.background = 'url(' + after + ')';
            });
            element.addEventListener('mouseout', function(event) {
                element.style.background = 'url(' + before + ')';
            });
        }
      }
    }
```

Could anyone help me please? I'm out of thougts... A user on stackoverflow helped me with the JS code, but it was with querySelector(), so I found, that when I need to make it work for all of the elements, I have to use querySelectorAll() with a FOR loop...

Comment: Use `for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {` instead of yours

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy um, not all browsers support let...

Comment: @epascarello oh!! Then he has to create a scope per iteration.. For that, the best choice would be `.forEach`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Comment: This is a classic and has been asked numerous times, read this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Comment: While the duplicate shows why your code gives the result that it does, the simple fact is that you don't need the `element` variable at all inside the handler. Instead use `this.style.background...`. You do however need to capture the `before` and `after` in a new scope on each iteration if you're going to take that approach.